# Pandas Dataframe of dates with missing data selection acting strangely

Tags: pandas, dataframe

When there is missing data in a Pandas DataFrame the indexing is not working as I would expect it it.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [datetime(2011, 1, 1),  datetime(2013, 1, 1)], 
                   'b' : [datetime(2010, 1, 1), datetime(2014, 1, 1)]})
df > datetime(2012, 1, 1)
```

works as expected:

```
    a       b
0   False   False
1   True    True
```

but if there is a missing value

```
none_df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [datetime(2011, 1, 1),  datetime(2013, 1, 1)],
                        'b' : [datetime(2010, 1, 1), None]})
none_df > datetime(2012, 1, 1)
```

the selection returns all True

```
    a       b
0   True    True
1   True    True
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Is this desired behavior?

Python 3.5 64bit, Pandas 0.18.0, Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the behavior is unusual.

This is a work-around solution:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda col: col > datetime(2012, 1, 1))
       a      b
0  False  False
1   True  False
```